# Convert extremly nested JSON to CSV using python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I'm having trouble converting below JSON to csv esepcially the details.kpis results section as it's quite nested. I'm trying to use pandas and the JSON_Normalize function but even if I give the correct record path and meta it's not helping. Below is the JSON, and I suggest pasting it into http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ to better understand as it neatly visualizes it. My end goal would be to get it to look similar to the ouput of this site that converts json to csv (https://data.page/json/csv). Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Please find the JSON here

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Swam8LnKRA17Yo_Um0OdFXpN9nHbOqNMFIEHC2Gcgr8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You can't really have a format with several 1:n relations like your JSON example fold into a records based format like CSV.  You are kind of recreating a format like YAML with indentations to indicate relations ?

Comment: I've been told I need to get this into a database. Essentially it's store information that comes in via JSON and downloaded via API to the cloud and then processed before going into database

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace following in your json :

1. false with False/"false"
2. null with None

After this just run the json_normalize() function , it should work.
I am able to make it run.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. It's not working it's saying NotImplementedError. Can you please share the json you got it to work with?

Comment: Here is the json :  https://ctxt.io/2/AAAQ6UsyEw

Comment: Hmm it's saying context has expired can you please try again?

Comment: https://ctxt.io/2/AAAQ6dV8Fg